# Which Sitecore library does the FieldViewModel class reside in?

Tags: sxa, sitecore-forms

I'm investigating Sitecore Forms on Sitecore 9.1 and am trying to create a custom form element as explained here https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-form-element.html

My using statements are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Mvc;
using Sitecore.Collections;
using Sitecore.ExperienceForms;

namespace xxxxxxxxxx.Feature.SitecoreForms.Models
{
    public class CourseViewModel : FieldViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

But on FieldViewModel I'm getting a compile error:

**The type or namespace name 'FieldViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I'm not sure which nuget package would include FieldViewModel... any ideas? I can't seem to find anything online

The Sitecore nuget packages I have installed in the project so far are:

- Sitecore.Analytics
- Sitecore.ExperienceForms
- Sitecore.Kernel
- Sitecore.Mvc
- Sitecore.XConnect

(All v9.1.0)

What am I missing? any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.dll`.

The full class name with namespace is

> `Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields.FieldViewModel`

Comment: Perfect - I added ```Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc``` nuget package and it's working now - thank you!